Replit not displaying results?
enter image description here When I run my code, it does not give me results. It just says 'Run' on the console page. It does not allow me to see results or interact with the code at all.
restarted replit. created a new repl. logging in to a different account.

Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Quick guess: do you even call your main function?

In Python, unlike some other languages, main() is not special.  That function is not called automatically.  You have to explicitly call it.

You defined the main() function but didn't actually call it!
Here's how you can fix it:
def miles_to_kilometers(miles):
    return miles * 1.60934

def main():
    # Prompt the user for the number of miles driven
    miles = float(input("Enter the number of miles driven: "))

    # Convert miles to kilometers
    kilometers = miles_to_kilometers(miles)

    # Display the total miles and kilometers
    print(f"{miles} miles is equal to {kilometers:.2f} kilometers.")

# Call the main function
main()

Alternatively, you can use:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

So, main() will only be called when the script is directly ran rather than when it is imported as a module in some other script.
